# Change date string format in android

Tags: java, android, date-format, android-date

I am getting date string from XML parsing like this:  2012-04-05 07:55:29 +05.30

Now, I want this string as : 05-April-2012

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

First parse this to date.

```
String time = "Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+03:00 (FLE Daylight Time)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);


SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String s=sdf.format(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

you can split everything seperately, and format however you want like that;

```
public String getDateFromString(String dateString){
    if(dateString!=null){
        String[] dateRoot=dateString.split(" ");
        String ymd=dateRoot[0];
        String hms= dateRoot[1];
        String[] calRoot=ymd.split("-");
        int year=Integer.parseInt(calRoot[0]);
        int month=Integer.parseInt(calRoot[1]);
        int day=Integer.parseInt(calRoot[2]);

        String[] timeRoot=hms.split(":");
        int hour=Integer.parseInt(timeRoot[0]);
        int minute=Integer.parseInt(timeRoot[1]);
        int second=Integer.parseInt(timeRoot[2]);

        String newFormat =  day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

        return newFormat;
        }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

consider,

```
String date="2012-04-05 07:55:29 +05.30";
//split the above string based on space
String[] dateArr=date.split(" ");

//Now in dateArr[0] you will have 2012-04-05, split this based on "-" to get yy,mm,dd
String[] yymmdd=dateArr[0].split("-");

//Now in get month name using a String array
String months[12]={"Jan","Feb","Mar","April","May","June","July","Aug","Sept","oct","Nov","Dec"};

//Now index to the above array will be your yymmdd[1]-1 coz array index starts from 0
String yy=yymmdd[0];
String dd=yymmdd[2];
String mm=months[Integer.parseInt(yymmdd[1])-1];

//Now you have the dd,mm,and yy as you need, So you can concatenate and display it

String myDate=dd+"-"+mm+"-"+yy;

//myDate will have the string you need
```

Answer (score 1):

use `("dd-MMMMMMMMM-yyyy")` as a DateStringFormat

Comment: what for? ... i realy don't care ... i'm just pointing that there is no such format in java like `MMMMMMMMM` ... are you writing an answers only to write something?

Comment: no you point me that there was no such format in java like that, then i'm asking you to write the correct one, btw take a look at this before downvote http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/DateFormatwithSimpleDateFormat.htm

Comment: i had change my vote since it's working but still `MMMM` for full month is enough(this is not my -1)

Comment: thanks for change, but it still seems like -1, you sure changed it ?